# in Node.js I want to link my application with my paypal account and i need paypal email id in my application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

In Node.js I want to link my application with my Pay pal account no need of payment and all just need to link after linking I need to show Pay pal account's email id in my application, I tried multiple ways but not its getting

I tried this:

```
`const axios = require('axios');
'A21AAJGW3oouvCLFdMI7U9m820Fh6c9JaFwxa8qT3RC3bvCHH0Cem79hjr4-kvc2mSMbVUD_n-zMtahnHtw_xpSJOQYzIGkBQ'(TOKEN);
       
     const scopes = 'Openid profile email'
         const userInfoUrl = `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/oauth2/userinfo?schema=paypalv1.1`;
         
         const headers = {
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         };
         
         axios.get(userInfoUrl, { headers })
           .then(response => {
        const userInfo = response;
         console.log('User Info:', userInfo);
           })
           .catch(error => {
         
           });
         `
```

the response I got :
`data: { user_id: 'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/m8c24nMzyNMU2xOGRtYshnfOkmcDAQv-Hy3x3m4uqoU', sub: 'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/m8c24nMzyNMU2xOGRtYshnfOkmcDAQv-Hy3x3m4uqoU' }`

**in data object**
but I need the email id of the Pay pal account

and then I tried something with redirect Uri but then its showing and error `#incorrect_redirect_uri or #invalid_client_id"`

I tried using
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo?schema=openid in **userInfoUrl**
but same result